# ListPlot as a function of a variable

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, functions

I was writing the following code. Now I am a bit stuck with a problem. Can anyone help?
My code lies below:

```
vec1 = With[{v1 = {0, 1, 0}, v2 = {1, 0, 0}}, 
   Table[With[{r = 
       RandomVariate[
        CircularRealMatrixDistribution[3]]}, (r.#) & /@ {v1, v2}], 
    2000]];
vec2 = With[{v3 = {0, 1, 0}, v4 = {1, 0, 0}}, 
   Table[With[{r = 
       RandomVariate[
        CircularRealMatrixDistribution[3]]}, (r.#) & /@ {v3, v4}], 
    2000]];
{A1, B1} = Transpose[vec1];
{C1, D1} = Transpose[vec2];
vYZ = {0, 1, 0}; 
mapping = 
  CoordinateTransformData[{"Cartesian" -> "Hyperspherical", 3}, 
   "Mapping"];
A1Map = mapping /@ A1;
r1 = Transpose[A1Map][[1]];
\[Theta]1 = Transpose[A1Map][[2]] ;
\[Phi]1 = Transpose[A1Map][[3]] /Degree;

A2Map = mapping /@ C1;
r2 = Transpose[A2Map][[1]];
\[Theta]2 = Transpose[A2Map][[2]] ;
\[Phi]2 = Transpose[A2Map][[3]] /Degree;
angle1 = (\[Pi]/
     2 - (\[Pi] - VectorAngle[vYZ , #] & /@ A1)) *180/\[Pi] ;
angle2 = (\[Pi]/
     2 - (\[Pi] - VectorAngle[vYZ , #] & /@ C1))  *180/\[Pi];
SmoothHistogram[ \[Phi]1];
data = Transpose[{Cos[\[Theta]1], \[Phi]1}];
ListPlot[data]
```

Now I want to make this list plot as function of `angle1` and `angle2`. I mean if I put a condition on  `angle1 < 20` and  `angle2 > 20` then how the  `ListPlot[data]` will look like?
is it possible to do?

Comment: Use `Pick` to subset your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vec1 = With[{v1 = {0, 1, 0}, v2 = {1, 0, 0}}, 
   Table[With[{r = 
       RandomVariate[
        CircularRealMatrixDistribution[3]]}, (r.#) & /@ {v1, v2}], 
    2000]];
vec2 = With[{v3 = {0, 1, 0}, v4 = {1, 0, 0}}, 
   Table[With[{r = 
       RandomVariate[
        CircularRealMatrixDistribution[3]]}, (r.#) & /@ {v3, v4}], 
    2000]];
{A1, B1} = Transpose[vec1];
{C1, D1} = Transpose[vec2];
vYZ = {0, 1, 0};
mapping = 
  CoordinateTransformData[{"Cartesian" -> "Hyperspherical", 3}, 
   "Mapping"];
A1Map = mapping /@ A1;
r1 = Transpose[A1Map][[1]];
\[Theta]1 = Transpose[A1Map][[2]];
\[Phi]1 = Transpose[A1Map][[3]]/Degree;

A2Map = mapping /@ C1;
r2 = Transpose[A2Map][[1]];
\[Theta]2 = Transpose[A2Map][[2]];
\[Phi]2 = Transpose[A2Map][[3]]/Degree;
angle1 = (\[Pi]/2 - (\[Pi] - VectorAngle[vYZ, #] & /@ A1))*180/\[Pi];
angle2 = (\[Pi]/2 - (\[Pi] - VectorAngle[vYZ, #] & /@ C1))*180/\[Pi];
SmoothHistogram[\[Phi]1];
data = Table[
   If[angle1[[i]] < 20 && angle2[[i]] > 20, 
    Transpose[{Cos[\[Theta]1], \[Phi]1}][[i]], {0, 0}], {i, 1, 
    Length[angle1]}];
ListPlot[data]
```

[image: fig1]